# Select a batch from a matrix in a loop

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

Assume I have the following matrix:

```
X = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [70,80,90], [45,43,68], [112,87,245]])
```

I want to draw a batch of 2 random rows at each time loop, and send it to a function. For instance, a batch in iteration `i` can be `batch = [[4,5,6], [70,80,90]]`

I do the following:

```
X = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [70,80,90], [45,43,68], [112,87,245]])

def caclulate_batch(batch):
    pass


for i in range(X.shape[0]/2):
    batch = np.array([])
    for _ in range(2):
        r = random.randint(0, 5)
        batch = np.append(batch, X[r])
    caclulate_batch(batch)
```

There are two problems here: (1) It returns appended array (2) The random number can be repeated which can choose the same row many times. How can modify the code to fit my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

`r = np.random.randint(0, len(x), 2)` should get you the indices. That lets you use fancy indexing to get the subset: `batch = x[r, :]`.

If you want to accumulate arrays along a new dimension, as your loop does, use `np.stack` or `np.block` instead of `np.append`.

Answer (score 1):

(1) You can use [`numpy.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) instead of `append`. EDIT: But this function would be called when you have all your batch in a list like:

```
list = ([1,2], [3,4]) 
numpy.stack(list)
# gives [[1,2],
#        [3,4]]
```

(2) You can shuffle X array, loop through the results and extract two by two. Look at [`numpy.random.shuffle`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html)

It would look like that:

```
S = np.random.shuffle(X)

for i in range(S.shape[0]/2):
    batch = S[i*2:i*2+1]
    caclulate_batch(batch)
```

Comment: While your program does not do what OP's does, I suspect that it is what OP is actually trying to do.

Comment: I think you might need `, :` or `, ...` in your index (`S[i*2:i*2+1, :]`), but not in a place to test.